# Set TextView in While Loop for print Time

Tags: java, android, time, android-asynctask

```
protected String doInBackground(String... Url) {
  try {
      URL url = new URL(Url[0]);
      URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
      connection.connect();

      //Detect File Length
      int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

      //Locate Storage Location
      String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

      //Downloading File
      final InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

      //Save the Download File
      OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filePath + "/" + "Ardu_Vid.mp4");

      final byte data[] = new byte[fileLength];
      long total = 0;
      int count;

      long Start_Timee = System.currentTimeMillis();
      while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {

          total += count;
          output.write(data, 0, count);

          //publish the progress
          publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));

          Long End_Timee = System.currentTimeMillis();
          Log.e("Time_End", "" + End_Timee);

          final long timeDiff = End_Timee - Start_Timee;

      /************ Get Duration of Downloading ***************/

          Long allTimeForDownloading = (timeDiff * fileLength / total);
          Long remainingTime = allTimeForDownloading - timeDiff;
          int seconds = (int) (remainingTime / 1000) % 60 ;
          int minutes = (int) ((remainingTime / (1000*60)) % 60);
          Log.e("elapse",""+minutes+":"+seconds);
  //Problem is here
          textView.setText(""+minutes +" : "+ seconds);

      }// end while
```

My coding working fine but when I add `textView.setText` for print remaining time of download file its not working problem is I get left time throw loop but my text view not set Time dynamically by loop when I print time in log I get accurate result. Please help me.

Comment: you should not do UI operations in thread

Comment: i had  done my task ... without thead

Comment: If your background operation is doing some heavy work and you want your UI to be updated simultaneously then you should consider using a thread or Android AsyncTask which has a built in thread. This way your UI wont be blocked.

Comment: @DanishKhan What ever you write in `doInBackground()` executed in thread.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to interact with the Android UI from the background (worker) thread the `AsyncTask` is running on. This is not permitted in Android as the UI framework is not thread safe. It is [very well documented](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads) that you should only ever touch the UI from the main (UI) thread which Android creates for your application:

> Additionally, the Andoid UI toolkit is not thread-safe. So, you must not manipulate your UI from a worker thread—you must do all manipulation to your user interface from the UI thread.

This is, in fact, the entire purpose of `AsyncTask` and the way it is structured. `doInBackground` is run on the background (worker) thread, and the callback methods (such as `onProgressUpdate`) are called on the UI thread so that you can easily and safely interact with the UI in response to the progress and results of the task.

It seems that you are actually correctly doing this already for the percentage progress, where you call `publishProgress`. I don't know what you're doing with that data in `onProgressUpdate`, but I assume you're displaying it in the UI?

Based on that, one simple and easy (although not necessarily the best) solution would be to take advantage of the fact `publishProgress` and `onProgressUpdate` have a varargs method parameter and return not just the percentage progress but also `minutes` and `seconds` in the same call to `publishProgress`. Then, in `onProgressUpdate`, simply unpack the extra values and then update the `TextView` there instead.